# Exporting many rasters as .png maps

Tags: raster, qgis-3, print-composer

I'm not used to QGIS, and I'm working on a project that involves hundreds of .tiff rasters (interpolations) of attributes of the same place. (the rasters are not really related by time)

In order to export one single raster as a complete map I should click for 300 times on: 
Project > New print Layout > Put a map, a legend, a title and an arrow > Export as images.

Is there a way to automatically export every raster with his own legend and title (obtained from the name of the associated raster)?

Comment: QGIS has the Atlas Tool it takes a little time to setup the automation but it will export png/pdf automatically https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/automating_map_creation.html

Comment: @Mapperz: in this case, a standard use of atlas will probably not work as OP need always the same feature (polygon) for coverage as the aim is producing a time series. So a somehow different approach (using reports?) could be a solution.

Comment: @babel Then the Temporal Control can be used https://www.gispo.fi/en/open-software/geogiffery-in-2020-with-qgis-temporal-controller/

Comment: Thank you for your support. I tryed to use the Atlas and Report tools but they need some sort of polygon layers and not rasters to work properly. Am i missing some knowledge about the creation of a polygon made by multiple rasters? I also tryed to polygonize each raster but the result was a little bit messy. EDIT: i did not express very well: the rasters are not really related by time, they are just a bunch of information of the same land.

Comment: You just need to create a coverage layer to create atlas: create a polygon layer with the same extent as the raster, set it to invisible and select it in the atlas dialog as coverage. You can add in temporal tab of each raster properties dialog a distinct time. Than in print layout, elemet properties, select which time you want to visualize: if in QGIS main window all rasters are visible, print compiser changes to show only the raster containing this timestamp you selected. You may also assign "dummy" timestamps jzst for this purpose.

Comment: @babel Thank you so much, it took me some time to figure it out but now my work is way easier.

Comment: Great - a variant would be to create the same coverage layer (a copy) as often as you have raster layers and than create an atlas and use some data driven settings to show a diferent raster for each feature of the coverage layer.

Comment: See also here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/367715/88814